# Duplicate Training Data in Decision Tree Learning Algorithm

Tags: machine-learning, decision-tree, training-data

I have the following training data set where the first line shows the name of attributes.

```
S_Length, Se_Width, P_Length, P_Width, Predicate
5.1,3.5,1.4,0.2,Ili
4.9,3.0,1.4,0.2,Iri
4.7,3.2,1.3,0.2,Iyr
4.6,3.1,1.5,0.2,Ir
5.0,3.6,1.4,0.2,Po
5.4,3.9,1.7,0.4,II
4.6,3.1,1.5,0.2,Ir
5.0,3.4,1.5,0.2,Imt
4.6,3.1,1.5,0.2,Ir
```

In the above data set, in row 4,7, and 9, the data sets are duplicate. How does it affect the algorithm? Should I omit the repeated data?

Comment: If I am trying to predict if someone is a lottery winner based on attributes including the beer they drink, and then I include one zillion duplicates of a Bud drinker who won the lottery, what do you think will happen?

Comment: That's a very realistic example. So it is certain that duplicate data sets add unnecessary weight to a node, and should be removed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this is correctly gathered data (a random sample of some random process/problem) then you should never remove samples. This is just characteristics of your data, you have sampled two objects which have the same representation. Efficiently, this will weight this point more, which is a valid thing to do if the reality is like this. In short **never remove anything** unless you are **100% sure** that this is **due to error** or you want to achieve something not-standard (like bias estimator toward different distribution, approximate solution for computational efficiency etc.).

Comment: I can not entirely agree with you conclusion "**100% sure** that this is **due to error**". I would replace it by  "**100% sure** that you know what you are doing". There are many good reasons to keep and to remove these points. One of these reasons would be that you use SVMs with hard margins and one to speed up computation. Others are that these points unwelcomely(?) emphasis misclassification costs in other training methods, e.g., Decision Trees. Hence, this points have different impact on different training methods.

Comment: @CAFEBABE, sure, underlying assumption is "if you are using a standard setting". If you want to do something non standard you can even remove all the training samples and build model by hand ;) there are no rules then (answer edited)

Comment: (too little space, for real good discussion) You summarised my problem with your answer: **you** apply certain assumptions. These assumptions you  call then **standard setting** (it seems: statistical ML, empirical risk minimisation). However, as soon as you leave this setting, things get quite differently. E.g., in clustering, rule induction, and so on. I had to smile, when writing "know what you are doing" because you should never draw any conclusions in ML until you know what you are doing. Hence, question very relevant, however, too little details to give a 0/1 answer IMHO. Not bad ans. so

Comment: Just saw parts of it are contained in the title. DT doesn't make it easier.

Answer (score 0):

For statistical machine learning lejlot has given a very good answer. However, decision tree learning are a bit different. It uses a greedy search towards a good structure which might result in weird outcomes here. Historically this is because they come from a time when Machine Learning was more of an art (or engineering, but that sounds less sexy).
.

Before continuing we need two ensure two properties (the first has already been explained by lejlot)

1. This duplications are not due to an error in the data collection process
2. Your data is still i.i.d. in case you want to do LOO or CV, train, test, validation split. This one looks extremely important to me. If seen many example where this spoiled all properties of the statistical evaluation. Especially, train/test splits might be applied for pruning etc. If so and your examples are not independent you need to make sure that they end up in the same **fold**

For numerical data I would immediately become very suspicious that either of these is violated.

Given these assumption -- and in addition that you use C4.5 -- we can analyse the impact on the learned model. If we assume, that your classes are separable by a decision tree and you do not put up any constrains it doesn't make any difference. In this case you can actually safely remove them, however, keeping them doesn't make a big difference either on the classifications. However, the structure of the tree can be largely influenced by these added examples. Without calculating the actual values for `entropy`/`gini` index I assume that the first split will be on `S_Length =< 4.6`. And this is the most important result of these extra example: the greediness of C4.5 will drive the structure towards something which captures these examples very well. You could call that structure overfitting for a certain class.  This can be a problem if this difference is rather marginal compared to other features. SVMs would react here much nicer (not a surprise: statistical ML).

In total I would actually keep them and remove them. During inducing the structure of the tree i would ignore them and only calculate the structure on the remaining examples. However, for calculating the classifications in the leaves and for pruning I would use them.

The previous paragraph contains the most important recommendation: I would apply pruning on the tree in such a domain.